# Picking random elements from finite groups and subgroups (numbers theory)

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I'm having a specification of a cryptographic protocol, which defines the following finite group and subgroup of prime respectively safe prime order:

$\mathbb{G}_q \subset \mathbb{Z}_p^*$  with $p=563$ and $q=281$

I understand that $\mathbb{G}_q$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative finite group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$

But now, within some algorithms, some random values are picked as follows:

$w_1 \in_R  \mathbb{Z}_q$

$w_2 \in_R  \mathbb{G}_q$

What does the first group mean? I don't understand, from which domain are the numbers now taken? I was thinking about taking random number from $\{1,...,280\}$ for both variables, but that is probably wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first group is the additive group of integers modulo $q, $ so numbers from $0$ to $280.$ The second group consists of quadratic residues modulo $563,$ which will be a collection of numbers between $1$ and $562.$